# Trying to create a function to send email, but it's not working..new to php...what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, function, email

```
function SendEmail() {

    $to      = $email;  
    $subject = 'Sales | Purchase Instructions';  
    $message = ' 

    Thank you for your purchasing 'My Product'.

    Your account information 
    ------------------------- 
    Name:   'Your Name'
    Email:  'Your Email' 

    ------------------------- 

    You can purchase our product by clicking on the purchase button, entering product name, and quantity in the provided boxes, and then click purchase.;  
    $headers = 'From:My Company <me@mycompany.net>' . "\r\n";  


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);  
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem with your quotation marks. You use `'` to encapsulate your strings, but you also use these marks inside the strings, so it does not work, the interpreter does not know where your string end and raises an error. So you should either not use the same quotation marks to encapsulate the strings that you use also inside it, or have to escape the quotation marks inside the string (by putting a `\` in front of it). My suggestions would be to use `"` around the string as you do not use these quotation marks inside the string.

You should know that there is a difference if you use `'` or `"` to encapsulate a string. When you use `"` variables inside the string will be replaced by their values, but not when you use `'`.

Comment: This code actually works fine by itself, doesn't work from within the 'SendMail' function, I thought it was something to do with the }, or { being in the wrong places

Comment: The curly braces are at the right place. In the code you posted above only the quotation marks are wrong.

Comment: @Zcast If it works fine then you have error reporting turned off. The syntax highlighting on this site even tells you the quotes are misused. Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before your `$to` and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$name = 'MonkeyZeus';
$message = 'Hi there '.$name.', <--this is a variable but this is a literal quote inside a quote --> \'';

echo $message;

?>
```

The expected output is:

**Hi there MonkeyZeus, <--this is a variable but this is a literal quote inside a quote --> '**

Comment: Ok, with all your help it's actually working now (When I say working, I mean it's actually sending emails now).  Thanks to all of you.